# Center align 2 fixed width divs side by side within parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get 2 divs centered exactly within a parent div. Both child divs take the height of the parent div. I've tried float:left and right with margin: 0 auto. I don't want one div centered while the other is offset a little. I would like div 1 right side to be in the exact center while div 2 left side to be in the exact center too. (I would prefer using CSS but if needed JS would be fine).

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="green">
    <div class="div1">
        Div 1
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
       Div 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.green {
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#9fbe3c;
}
.div1 {
    height:100%;
    width:141px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.div2 {
    width:141px;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    top:-50px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/Gad4C/)

For some reason div 2 was being pushed out of the parent block. I've tried display:inline-block and that did not work so I just used position relative.

Comment: Can you provide some visual(image would be better). As not able to understand what output you want.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/umrKp)?

Comment: [IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/2412ni0.png[/IMG] @Tushar Yes, exactly, for some reason, I applied your changes and both divs are on the left side of the parent block

Comment: Did you apply text-align: center to .green? If yes then please update the fiddle so I can find whats going wrong.

Comment: @tushar ahh yes, I forgot to add that. That helps a million! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like [this](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/umrKp)

HTML

```
<div class="green">
    <div class="div1">
        Div 1
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
       Div 2
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.green {
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#9fbe3c;
  text-align: center;
}
.div1, .div2 {
    height:100%;
    width:141px;
    margin:0 auto;
  display: inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `text-align: center` and `display: inline-block` while removing the margin/float logic.

Here is the modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gad4C/9/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it. It's always the simple things that you always forget. Thanks so much!